# Is my argument correct to solve this textbook problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, infinity, pigeonhole-principle

The problem is from M.Bona's "A Walk through Combinatorics", Ch1 Prob 13:

> There are infinitely many pieces of paper in a basket, and there is a
>   positive integer written on each of them. We know that no matter how
>   we choose infinitely many pieces, there will always be two of them so
>   that the difference of the numbers written on them is at most ten million. Prove that there is an integer that has been written on
>   infinitely many pieces of paper.

My attempt: Let $A$ a multiset of all positive integers written on the infinite pieces of paper. My claim is that (i) $A$ has a finite number of distinct numbers and (ii) there is at least one number from $A$ that is repeated for a an infinite number of times.
If (i) is true then (ii) should be true for if not then $A$ must have an infinite number of distinct positive integers.
(i) is true otherwise we can make a selection $B$ as follows: Let $a$ the minimum element of $A$, keep adding $b\gt10^7$. If the result is a member of $A$ then add it to $B$. This "algorithm" should not terminate if $A$ has infinite distinct numbers and then $B$ should be a selection of infinite many pieces from $A$ but no 2 numbers have a difference at most 10 million, *i.e.* a contradiction. In addition it is possible to construct a non empty $A$ for example taking $\{1,2,3\}$ an infinite number of times.
If (i) is true then so is (ii) and this proves the problem's statement

I am not familiar with the concept of infinity and so I found this problem challenging. The book provides a different answer which I haven't digested yet, maybe I'll post a different new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is almost correct. You can’t use a fixed $b>10^7$, however: it’s possible that $a$ is the only element of $A$ in the set $\{a+kb:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. You can avoid this problem by arguing as follows.

Let $A_0=A$. Let $a_0=\min A_0$, let $B_0=\{a\in A:a\le a_0+10^7\}$, and let $A_1=A_0\setminus B_0$; by hypothesis $B_0$ is finite, so $A_1$ is non-empty, and we can let $a_1=\min A_1$.

In general, given an infinite multiset $A_n$, let $a_n=\min A_n$, let $B_n=\{a\in A:a\le a_n+10^7\}$, and let $A_{n+1}=A_n\setminus B_n$; $B_n$ is finite, so $A_{n+1}$ is infinite, and the recursive construction can continue.

In this way we find a sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $A$ such that $a_n+10^7<a_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Clearly $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ has no two elements within $10^7$ of each other.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is right, but your explanation of makes it a bit hard to see the crucial step. It can look a bit like you're having trouble explaining *why* there's always a $b$ to add, and is trying to make up for it by adding proofy-sounding fluff around it.

Here's how I would write basically the same idea:

> We will prove the claim in contraposed form:
>
> > **If** there is *no* integer that appears infinitely many times (that is, every integer appears at most finitely many times), **then** we can choose infinitely many papers such that the difference of any two of those numbers will exceed $10^7$.
>
> Namely, let $a_1$ be the smallest number on any of the papers, and construct a sequence $a_2, a_3, a_4, \ldots$ as follows:
>
> For each $n$, let $a_{n+1}$ be the smallest number larger than $a_n+10^7$ that appears on any paper. *There is always such a number, because each number less than this limit exists in only finitely many copies, so there are only finitely many papers with a number less than the limit. Since there are infinitely many papers, some of them must be above the limit.*
>
> This produces an infinite increasing sequence of numbers with a step size larger than $10^7$, so no two numbers in the sequence will be closer than that.

I don't think it would improve the presentation of the proof to phrase it such that the word "multiset" is mentioned -- even though multisets are of course one way to model the situation.